# How to get .java file from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Have to submit homework for my class but as a .java file, but I have no idea on how to get just the .java source file. They don't want .class, .jar, or .zip. Any idea on how to do this? I am new to Eclipse so thank you for any help.

I have tried clicking on the class itself in the eclipse window and exporting it from there but it just tries to turn it into a .jar file.

Answered than you so much!

Comment: just right click on file and choose copy

Comment: Thank you sweet, I hope you have a day as wonderful as you are!!!

Comment: @Deadpool use the answer box ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple way to get the `.java` file from eclipse

1) You can simple right click on file and select copy

[image]

2) Second approach is right click on project -> select resources, there you can see the `Location` of project, so you can copy directly from that path

[image]